# Adding acheckbox to every row in a list

Tags: android, android-listview

i am trying to add a checkbox to the contacts list. how do i add a checkbox to every row in a list and retrieve those checked values.??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you may be displaying contact information in a list ,assuming you are using table,you can make one td tag having input type checkbox name as an array

and when you click on checkbox and posting the page only selected checkbox value is sended